# SVN save account on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, shell, svn

I saw many topic about svn automatically save svn account on linux.  SVN still required login credentials when I checkout or update.

.I have tested following those instructions with **preshare**-**key **from ssh client to server but somehow it didn't work. Although I connect via ssh with preshare-key from client to server, and config at server to auto save.

May I have any advice on this?

Comment: There is some confusion in your question between svn and ssh. While both have client and server, these are different applications that do different things. Now what do you want to accomplish? Which commands do you run? What do you expect and what happens instead? Please [edit] and tell us.

Comment: To consider this a programming question, you'll need to share the exact code (with personal inforrmation obscured) AND exact text of error messages so readers can understand your problem. If you can only post general descriptions as above then [su] or [unix.se] may be better for you. Read their help about on-topic questions, chose one site to post to and then delete this version of your question. Good luck.